# Relation between Symmetric algebra and Universal enveloping algebra as Lie algebras.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Assume $L$ satisfies PBW theorem. We can associate two Lie algebras with $L$:

1) $U(L):$ the universal enveloping algebra. Here the Lie bracket is defined by $[x,y]=x*y-y*x$ where $*$ is the product induced from tensor product.

2)$S(L):$ the symmetric algebra. Here the Lie bracket is defined by extending the Leibniz rule $[xy,z]=x[y,z]+[x,z]y.$

**Q) Are theses two Lie algebras isomorphic as Lie algebras.**

Comment: I have defined the Lie bracket. With this bracket $S(L)$ is a Lie algebra. There is no grading involved to define this Lie algebra.

Comment: Yes. Surely you can define Lie product in the Symmetric Lie algebra in many ways. Given a vector space, there may be more than one way to define Lie bracket. My question is regarding the Lie bracket defined in the question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Exercise: prove that there is a unique Lie bracket on $S(L)$ that restricts to the original Lie bracket on $L$ and that satisfies the Leibniz rule as given by the OP.

Comment: @tessellation Have you looked at explicit cases such as $L$ non-abelian 2-dimensional, or $L=\mathfrak{sl}_2$?

Comment: @YCor Hi. I am quite new to this subject and my knowledge is limited to wiki entries and some basic lecture notes. Therefore I am not even capable of understanding  $\mathfrak{sl}_2$. Therefore it would be really helpful if you could give some hints regarding whether this is even true or not..

Comment: To start with, you could compare the centers. The center of the universal enveloping algebra is known.

Comment: yes, this is a corollary of Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witten Theorem.